# Routing network based on MAC address on macOS and Windows

Tags: windows, networking, macos, mac-address

On Linux distros that use Gnome's Network Manager subsystem, the `nmcli` (Network Manager CLI) allows you to add an ethernet connection for a device with a specific MAC address using `nmcli con add type ethernet mac <mac_address> ...` . Is there a way to do the same for macOS and Windows? I've looked into `route` and `networksetup` on macOS, and `netsh` on Windows, but I couldn't figure out how to route traffic based on MAC address with these command line tools.

Comment: Ethernet is a connectionless data link technology with no routing (Ethernet is at layer 2, and routing is typically a layer 3 concept), so it's hard to understand what you're actually trying to do. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I was just referring to the `type` parameter in the `nmcli` command

Comment: I know these protocols and the traditional Unix network stack quite well, but I don't have much experience with Gnome's Network Manager / nmcli world. So I can't quite figure out your question because you've phrased it in NM-specific terms which are a bit nonstandard and weird. I would love it if you could say what it is this command actually accomplishes for you, and I could tell you how to accomplish the same thing on OSes that don't use Gnome. Like "I'd like to add a static ARP mapping", or "I'd like to add a VLAN virtual interface to an existing Ethernet interface".